# Load a structure.sql into a rails database via rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema

`rake db:schema:load` will load a `schema.rb` file into a rails database. Is there a way to load a `structure.sql` file into the database through rake or do I just need to do this manually?

Comment: What does it mean to load a file into a rails database? Does this mean to create a database structure (the tables, the table names, and the attributes) based off the file?

Answer (score 103):

Use `rake db:structure:load`, which will load `db/structure.sql`.

[Update]

If you want to load another file, you can specify its path via

- `SCHEMA` environment variable (Rails 5.0 or later)
- `DB_STRUCTURE` environment variable (Rails 4.x)

For example, run

```
rake db:structure:load SCHEMA=db/another.sql
```

or

```
rake db:structure:load DB_STRUCTURE=db/another.sql
```

Comment: Or specify file path via ENV variable like this: `rake db:structure:load DB_STRUCTURE=db/another.sql`

Comment: In order to specify the path of SQL file, use the `SCHEMA` environment variable (not `DB_STRUCTURE`) like `rake db:structure:load SCHEMA=db/another.sql`.

Comment: Don't confuse structure with schema. `SCHEMA` is for .rb files (schema) and `DB_STRUCTURE` is for .sql files (db structure) https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1505f8b69209c02ff60f124220590bde20bb7c09/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L283

Comment: It seems that on the latest code, the environment variable `SCHEMA` is used. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b6d5e46311d7ea59539c1f45c6ffb269eeb23912/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L303

Comment: Indeed. I was referring to 4.2.5.2.

Comment: The behavior changed on this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/99e57a8dccb700375c674c6c7872025f0022f0db

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 36):

Just use

```
rake db:setup
```

which will use either `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` depending on your configuration.

Comment: Depending on what configuration? Could you please add links to some docs?

Comment: In your `application.rb` you can write the  `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`, default is `:schema`. The [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#setup-the-database) are unclear on this: they just say `rake db:setup` will load from schema, which might or might take the configuration into account (does schema mean the database schema, which is stored as configured, or `schema.rb` only). As usual the source is definitive: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6201e62cc49720e9133759e9a19fd1cc11ab73e1/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L175

Answer (score 8):

Use the database's own SQL load mechanism.

For Postgres this should work (at least if the database exists and you don't need a password):

```
psql -d databaseName < db/structure.sql
```

On Heroku where rake db:setup doesn't work as you can't create a database like that you can do this:

```
heroku pg:psql < db/structure.sql
```

Answer (score 6):

Once you load your schema, you can try:

```
rails dbconsole < structure.sql
```

OR

```
rails db < structure.sql
```

Comment: OMG, this is a game changer. How am I only learning this now, after almost 8 years of Rails development!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you want to load a file that is not the default `db/structure.sql`.

For rails 4.2 and earlier, use

`DB_STRUCTURE=some_file.sql rake db:structure:load`

As of rails 5 use

`SCHEMA=some_file.sql rake db:structure:load`

Answer (score 3):

Make your seeds.rb file like:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

  sql = File.read('db/structure.sql')
  statements = sql.split(/;$/)
  statements.pop  # the last empty statement

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    statements.each do |statement|
      connection.execute(statement)
    end
  end
end
```

[Source](http://panupan.com/2013/01/18/seed-your-rails-app-by-importing-from-sql/).

Comment: I added `statements.reject! { |statement| statement.match?(%r{ar_internal_metadata|schema_migrations}) }` to remove rails default tables that somehow already exist.